# Solr Spatial - Indexing bean

Tags: solr, spatial, solrj, jts

I need to index on Solr a bean that contains a generic spatial field (generally, a polygon).

I configured my Solr core schema in this way (following the tutorial [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Spatial+Search)):

```
<fieldType name="area"   class="solr.RptWithGeometrySpatialField" spatialContextFactory="org.locationtech.spatial4j.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
           autoIndex="true"
           validationRule="repairBuffer0"
           distErrPct="0.025"
           maxDistErr="0.001"
           distanceUnits="kilometers" />
....
<field name="location" type="area" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
```

My bean class is as follows:

```
public class MySolrBean {

    @Field("id")
    private String id;

    @Field("location")
    private Geometry location;

    // getters and setters...
}
```

where `Geometry` refers to `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry` (`jts-1.13`)

When I try to add a new bean to the index with `SolrClient.addBean(Object)` I get the following error:

```
Unable to parse shape given formats "lat,lon", "x y" or as WKT because java.text.ParseException: Unknown Shape definition [com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Polygon:POLYGON ((1 0, 0.9980267284282716 0.0627905195293134, 0.9921147013144779 0.12533323356430...]
```

where WKT representation of my polygon is prefixed by the class fqn. I remember I saw a similar problem some time ago, this time when using `ZonedDateTime`: I changed my code to use `java.util.Date` and everything worked.

Though now I would not know which class to use instead of `com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry` and surfing the web I didn't find any documentation about that.

Anyone can help me out sorting this issue?

**EDIT**

Forgot to mention I'm using the latest `Solr` and `Solrj` distribution: 6.5.1

Comment: Have you tried it without the fqn at all?  Just use `POLYGON((...`

Comment: @GregHNZ yes I tried changing the `MyBean.location` field to `java.lang.String` and passing in a WKT valid string. It succeeds. Though the question stands: what class should / could I use to have that field strongly typed? Reason is: I wouldn't want to keep marshalling / unmarshalling WKT to Geometry for perfomance sake and code readability.

Comment: @StefanoCazzola, did you figure out with the problem? I have same problem :(

Comment: @KostyaVyrodov sort of. Instead of using`Geometry` as field type, I used `String` and passed in a WKT formatted string (see here for reference https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text). Didn't manage to have it working with strong typization.